# BMX frame logo identification

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

I have a BMX frame with a stylised "h" on the rear forks. Can anyone ID it for me?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if running the photo through an image search would give any results

Comment: Best guess for this image: plywood

Comment: Well I tried making line art out of it, and using google image search with "bmx logo" as well.    Can you go back to whereever you got this bike and ask for more info?